# Filtering on a field that is not included in the mapping in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have an Order object that has a Customer child object.  Before I did not have a many-to-one relationship set up and I was simply returning the CustomerID.  With that approach I could easily filter by CustomerID.  Now I set up a many-to-one relationship and I am unsure of how to filter by CustomerID when I load a collection of Orders.  Any advice?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please post your entity code and mappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are after sothing like the following

`IList<Order> orders = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order))

.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer))

.Add(Expression.Eq("CustomerId", customerId))

.List<Order>();`

Comment: That was the case.  I didn't realize you could call CreateCriteria twice.  Pretty cool stuff.  Thanks!!